# loading xml document error in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to load a document with xml in c#
the name of xml file is variable, here is problem...

```
string filename="test01.xml";
XmlDocument root = new XmlDocument();
root.Load(filename);
```

the above code give me error: unable to connect to remote server or unable to load 
but the following code works

```
 XmlDocument root = new XmlDocument();
 root.Load("test01.xml");
```

why is that?

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from those lines

Comment: There's no reason why these shouldn't both work, unless there's other code somewhere that you're not showing here.

Comment: When you debug through the code, what's the _actual_ line of code which throws the exception?

Comment: i am guessing the path of the filename would be incorrectly fed in to Load

Comment: root.LoadXml(filename) would work as well.

Comment: im sure the error is from that part, at least VS2010 points to it and i even opened with a new blank project

Comment: @Morpheus- no it wouldn't, that overload expects XML, not a filename, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx .. and to the upvoters: ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to specify the whole path (absolute path) to the file (not only the filename).

So instead of writing ***"test01.xml"*** you can try to write ***"C:\[... path to the file here]\test01.xml"*** and it should work as intended.

**If you specify only the file name**, the application will probably look for the file in the current directory (value in `Environment.CurrentDirectory`). I just tested this in a sample application.

It's worth mentioning that if you use `FileName` property from `OpenFileDialog` class as a case with 'using variable', it contains PATH to the file (despite its name ;)).

Comment: that's it!!! thanks a lot, man, i have been scratching my head for some time because of this. can't believe it was cause by such small thing....

Answer (score 0):

Does your XML contains DTD declaration with URL? Most probably parser tries to resolve it, and fails, because, say, automatic proxy does not accept its request.